# Xamarin.iOS system exception

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am getting this error as shown on the picture while trying to debug on my device.

Could anyone explain what this means and possibly how to fix it?

I do not have any button called "logindKnap"

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What part of error message is not clear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look if you have recently removed interface builder connections to code. If you have removed the connection in code you can still have a referencing outlet in interface builder.

Open your storyboard file and check that you do not have any references from your components to a logindKnap. Then save to rebuild the wrapper in xamarin.

Comment: That was what caused the errors! Thanks a lot, marked as answered :)